# How can I have Spring-integration diagram shown in Netbeans IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, netbeans, spring-integration

I am working on a project where we use Spring-Integration with Eclipse and Spring tools plugins.
In this case we can open Spring-Integration xml file in design mode and have a nice diagram.
I'd like to use Netbean, but I don't know how I can see the Sring-Integration diagram.
Help is welcome, as workaround.

Thanks